# why local user try to authenticate with active directory which is not in domain?

Tags: dns, active-directory, dotnetnuke

we are working for the active directory aunthetication in dotnetnuke and we have done it successfully but there is a problem which can be more clear with the following picture and information below the image.we configure the active directory for the "DNA_NTD domain" and the "DGIWEB" is the server name.

[image]

Note that the user “dgiwe” doesn’t exist in our DNA_NTD domain (yet it is a local user on the DGIWEB server.  Additionally, the domain it is attempting to use (the server name) is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected behavior, since the user account isn't a domain account it is reflected as a "Machine" account which that distinction is done by putting the servername in for the domain.

Comment: i am very glad to see answer from you.because i am reader of your blog continusoly from last Dec when i started working on dotnetnuke. can i know how to stop this expected behaviour ?

Comment: There is no way around this as this is just how Active Directory works.  The "anonymous" user could work, but that would cause other problems.